# Changing image with onclick for 100's of different image links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to javascript and just trying to figure out how to get 100's of image links to change to a specific image once they've been clicked.

I know you can add ID's, but having to make 100's or 1000's of ID's will be a pain. Maybe someone will be able to help me with this issue, or direct me in the correct direction. Thank you!

```
<a id="click"><img id="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://yahoo.com','_blank');"></a>
<a id="click"><img id="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank');"></a>
<a id="click"><img id="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://monster.com','_blank');"></a>

document.getElementById('click').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('change').src = "http://i.imgur.com/0eaWvgw.jpg";
}
```

Comment: use class and get this context on clicked image

Comment: DOM ID should be unique.

Comment: Are all images being changed to the same image? Also ID should always be applied to one element only. Classes should be used otherwise

Comment: Thank you for all the replies, I'm just learning JavaScript and I'm more familiar with CSS, but It seems as though JavaScript is what I need to get this accomplished. Here is my site if it helps any http://slotogifts.x10.mx/ the images are going to be the ones I supplied in the first post. Here is also a jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/6tj7hdpt/11/

Thank you again, will try to implement the codes that I've been given.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery,

```
 $('a').on('click', function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/0eaWvgw.jpg')
    });
});
```

Comment: `Changing image with onclick for 100's of different image links` i dont see click event :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

- Use `common-class` over all the elements on which click event is to be bound
- Use jQuery `.on` method to register events over all the elements having specified `common-class`

Also note that you have attached `inline-click` event over `img` elements, which action is suppose to take place once `click` is dispatched ?

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //To prevent behavior of `a` elements
  $(this).find('img.change').prop('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/0eaWvgw.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="click">
  <img class="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://yahoo.com','_blank');">
</a>
<a class="click">
  <img class="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank');">
</a>
<a class="click">
  <img class="change" src="http://i.imgur.com/zS0lOud.jpg" onClick="window.open('http://monster.com','_blank');">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, an id is something that must be unique. A class is what you want to use. The class attribute is a space-separated list of words. In this case, we only need one class on all links. Now you put some JS on all these links, but you should instead write it like this:

```
<a class="change" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="image.png" />
</a>
```

The links will open the sites in  a new window or tab even on browsers with JavaScript disabled in that way.

Then we need to retrieve a list of all elements with the "change" class, and add an event listener for the click event on all of them.

```
var changeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.change');

var clickListener = function(e) {
  var imgElement = e.currentTarget.querySelector('img');
  imgElement.src = 'newimage.png';

  // technically, the image is only changed once so we can remove the
  // event listener once it has run on a link
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', clickListener);
};

for(var i=0, element; element = changeLinks[i]; ++i) {
  element.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
}
```